# Convert video.ts file into video.mp4 using ffmpeg

Tags: python, python-3.x, video, ffmpeg, subprocess

So I tried to convert a file named `video.ts` into `video.mp4` in Python and am getting the error:

`FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

Assuming `video.ts` is already loaded into the program and subprocess already imported.

This is due to the line:

`>>> subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', '-i', 'video.ts', 'video.mp4'])` but I don't know what's the problem.

I've opened the `video.ts` file and it seem to be working fine. Python version (3.8.2)

Comment: Try using absolute paths, you're probably executing the program in the wrong folder.

Comment: Do you have commas between the strings in the real code? If not, they'll be concatenated into `ffmpeg-ivideo.tsvideo.mp4`, which of course won't be found.

Comment: @TelmoTrooper I have tried that too, but it didn't work so I left it the same as it looks cleaner

Comment: @deltab I initially had with commas, but I tried other solutions including involving os.system hence why no commas, nevertheless, made no difference without commas as had same error

Comment: ***`ffmpeg -i video.ts video.mp4`***: Does it work if input this command, without commas, into a command window?

Comment: Solved it, foolishly assuming **ffmpeg** was preinstalled in the libraries, I though there could be no issue. Then tried installing **ffmpeg** as one last try and added to path in environment variables and it worked!. Btw, thanks for the help guys <3

Comment: Instead of editing your question to add the solution you are encouraged to add it as an answer. See the box below and the *Post Your Answer* button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone having this problem, download ffmpeg (will usually be in a zip), extract, go inside bin directory, and **copy path** (eg. location of folder\ffmpeg\bin). Then type in **environment variables** in start menu, add this path to the variable named **PATH** and save. DONE!

If there's still issues, restart your program, or further, your device